# Laravel 5.2 Login with id instead of email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Currently I've got the default Laravel 5.2 authentication mechanism. I'm trying to change that so the user can login with the id instead of the email. I can't really use the `username`-attribute in my controller, since I don't want the user to select the id. I still want to assign that via auto increment and email it to him. So my registration form is supposed to have the fields `email`, `password` and `password_confirmation` and my login form the fields `id` and `password`.
Is that possible without rewriting the whole thing? I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers you will see that laravel searchs the field email by default:

```
public function loginUsername()
{
    return property_exists($this, 'username') ? $this->username : 'email';
}
```

You can override this in your AuthController like this:

```
protected $username = 'id';
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: For some reason I felt like I can't use that because it would affect the registration, too. But of course you're right! Thank you!

Comment: It shouldn´t affect your registration process, give it a try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `attempt` method, see the code below or [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authenticating-users).

```
if (Auth::attempt(['id' => Request::input('id'), 'password' => Request::input('password')])) {
    // Your user is logged in.
}
```